# Processing - Blending fill colors with mouse movement

Tags: processing, gradient, interactive, blending

I saw this video the other day and am trying to replicate how its done.

It’s pretty straight forward but the thing I’m stuck on is how to get the drawn shapes to be more blurred and have a smooth gradient across them like the reference:

https://www.instagram.com/p/B_DjZCro2qm/

[Gradient reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkjs1.jpg)

Does anyone have an idea of how to blend the circle colors to make them seem more like a gradient?

```
PImage img;
int value = 0;
int size = 50;

void setup() {
  size(640, 800);
  frameRate(60);
  img = loadImage("blue.jpg");
  img.resize(width, height);
  background(img);
}

void draw() {
  //get the color at the mouse position
  color c = img.get(mouseX, mouseY);

  //change the fill to that color
  fill(c);
  noStroke();

  //draw a circle with that color when mouse pressed
  if(mousePressed) circle(mouseX, mouseY, size);;
}
```

Comment: There are two things which you have to consider here. First, in the example the color which is used is probably an average of all the colors in the circle **in the original picture**. So you have to refer to the original picture to get that color. Second: you have to **use math** so you know which pixels are in the "circle" and figure out the average color. Your next step should be to write the pseudocode to do all these things and then try your hand at it (and come back if you're stuck on something).

Comment: Thanks @laancelot, I needed to get the average color, that was the trick! `color getAverageColor(PImage img) {
  img.loadPixels();
  int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<img.pixels.length; i++) {
    color c = img.pixels[i];
    r += c>>16&0xFF;
    g += c>>8&0xFF;
    b += c&0xFF;
  }
  r /= img.pixels.length;
  g /= img.pixels.length;
  b /= img.pixels.length;
 
  return color(r, g, b);
}`

Answer (score 2):

As @laancelot pointed out, I needed to get the average color! Thanks

```js
color getAverageColor(PImage img) {
  img.loadPixels();
  int r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<img.pixels.length; i++) {
    color c = img.pixels[i];
    r += c>>16&0xFF;
    g += c>>8&0xFF;
    b += c&0xFF;
  }
  r /= img.pixels.length;
  g /= img.pixels.length;
  b /= img.pixels.length;
 
  return color(r, g, b);
}
```